# What's the fastest way to read a file full of strings (separated by newlines) in an array of unsigned char arrays (and vice versa)?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, file-io

Well, maybe the title is misleading a bit. All I want you to do is to take a quick look at the following two snippets and to give me some tips on how to improve the performance as much as possible without getting too exotic code. The code is needed to function on win32 only. Unfortunately STL containers are not an option right now.

To read the file...

```
bool TextFile::Read(const char *pFilePath)
{
    bool            bSuccess    = false;
    std::ifstream   oFile(pFilePath, std::ios_base::in);

    if(oFile.is_open())
    {
        std::string stLineNow;
        std::size_t siLineLength;

        if(this->pLines)
        {
            this->Clear();
        }

        this->stFilePath = pFilePath;

        oFile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        this->pLines = new unsigned char *[static_cast<unsigned int> (oFile.tellg())];
        oFile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

        for(this->ulLinesCount = 0; std::getline(oFile, stLineNow).good(); this->ulLinesCount++)
        {
            siLineLength = stLineNow.length() + 1;
            this->pLines[this->ulLinesCount] = new unsigned char[siLineLength];
            memcpy(this->pLines[this->ulLinesCount], stLineNow.c_str(), siLineLength);
        }

        bSuccess = true;

        oFile.close();
    }

    return bSuccess;
}
```

... and to save it...

```
bool TextFile::Save(const char *pFilePath)
{
    bool bSuccess = false;

    if(this->pLines)
    {
        std::ofstream oFile(pFilePath ? pFilePath : this->stFilePath, std::ios_base::out);

        if(oFile.is_open())
        {
            for(unsigned long ulPosition = 0; ulPosition < this->GetCount(); ulPosition++)
            {
                oFile << this->Get(ulPosition) << '\n';
            }

            bSuccess = true;

            oFile.close();
        }
    }

    return bSuccess;
}
```

... and please excuse the ugly formatting.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You seem to allocate too many lines: `this->pLines = new unsigned char *[static_cast<unsigned int> (oFile.tellg())];` allocates one line per character in the input file.

Comment: why can't you use stl containers? they are part of the language anyway

Comment: It's all fun a games until someone also wants UTF-16 support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well... what I would do is:

- Use memory-mapped files. That's THE fastest way of reading files;
- Then `memcpy()` all the file's contents in a new buffer;
- Then run through the buffer once and count the newlines;
- Make an array of as many pointers as there are newlines;
- Run through the buffer another time, and this time:

  - Replace the first byte of each newline with `0`.
  - Place a pointer to the start of each line in the pointer array.

*Voilà !*

Comment: +1 Although my gut feeling would say it will be faster to do a single pass. The pointer array will then need expand/be reallocated over time. For longer lines, this should be more efficient.

Comment: Hard to say. Maybe. A suitable data structure then has to be selected for the "expanding array of pointers". That however then depends on the data that needs to be read. Profiling needs to be done too. If a linked list can be used instead of an array, that would be good.

Comment: If you can afford to allocate an additional pointer per line, you could make a single pass through the memory-mapped area, searching for newlines, and then allocating the line plus an additional pointer in the same call, then use that pointer as a linked list, pointing to the next or previous line. Finally, when you're done, create the pointer array of the size (count it as you process), and fill it in, stepping through the singly linked list you created.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of memory allocations. It's a relatively expensive operation, when trying to be fast. That's why I opted for the two-pass approach. Of course, if the whole file consists of 5 enormously huge lines, then your approach will be faster. But I think it's a less likely scenario than a thousand small lines.

Comment: This works fine until it reaches the very last line which is a string that is not followed by a newline character. Also what would you do when it comes to saving the array of arrays? Looking forward to learn from you!

Comment: Vilx, You're right, of course, your approach is much better afterall. Forgive me, it's late and I'm taking quick breaks inbetween packing up the house :). Oliver K., the easiest approach would be to allocate a buffer 1 byte larger and fix the last character to '\0', I guess.

Comment: Thank you arke! I shouldn't try to write programs after 02:00 am!

Comment: What do you mean - "saving" the array of arrays? As in - saving to a file? Isn't that what the original file is?

Comment: Yes, saving to a file. And no, the strings / unsigned char arrays get modified once read in.

Comment: Well, if they get modified, then it's trickier. If they don't grow longer and new lines aren't created, then you can keep them in the same big buffer, and just write that out, along with a little extra info about how many lines there are and where each line starts (then you can read it in extra fast). But if that isn't the case (which it most likely isn't), then you'll have to write it out line-by-line. If you use the same memory-mapped files again, that should be pretty efficient anyway. Again - you can write extra info about the count of lines and the starting position of each.